# uWSGI does not start on startup

Tags: uwsgi

I have the following `/etc/init/uwsgi.conf`:

```
description "uWSGI"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]
respawn

env UWSGI=/var/www/my_project/venv/bin/uwsgi
env LOGTO=/var/log/uwsgi/emperor.log

exec $UWSGI --master --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --die-on-term --uid www-data --gid www-data --logto $LOGTO
```

As far as I can tell this is best practice as seen [here](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Upstart.html)

I also have `/etc/uwsgi/vassals/my_project_uwsgi.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
#application's base folder
base = /var/www/my_project

#python module to import
app = server
module = %(app)

home = %(base)/venv
pythonpath = %(base)

#socket file's location
socket = /var/www/my_project/%n.sock

#permissions for the socket file
chmod-socket    = 666

callable = app

#location of log files
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log

processes = 10
```

Now, is it that uWSGI isn't being called on startup, or is it that there's something wrong with the overall config? (uWSGI config, nginx config, my app logic, file permissions etc?)

I think that the init script simply isn't being run. The reason why I think this is that when I run the init script manually, ie `# /var/www/my_project/venv/bin/uwsgi --master --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --die-on-term --uid www-data --gid www-data --logto /var/log/uwsgi/emperor.log` then everything works as it should. On the other hand when I reboot the machine `# reboot` then nothing seems to happen. The uWSGI isn't running after reboot and more importantly, NOTHING is written on `/var/log/uwsgi/emperor.log`. From my experience with uWSGI, if you have a configuration mistake something is still written to `emperor.log`. So I conclude that `/etc/init/uwsgi.conf` isn't being run on startup.

How can I check this, and fix it?

EDIT: Update. tried `sudo apt install upstart`. Also [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611982/how-to-register-an-upstart-service) says that upstart needs inotify to detect changes in files in `/etc/init`, so I also did `sudo apt install inotify-tools`. However my script still doesn't run on startup.

Answer (score 1):

This solved it

```
apt install upstart-sysv
```

Inspired by [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers) (Under "Permanent switch back to upstart)

Comment: Did this force you to use upstart for other system services as well?